# How to update the value of state variable passed to function in react?

Tags: reactjs

I was trying to add a state variable which would update on changing form input .I have a function `handleSubmit` which would be called on submitting the form. I wanted to pass the updated value of my state variable to another function `all` inside my `handleSubmit` function but the value passed to the function never gets updated even after many times submitting the form.

It's something like this...

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      let colors = new Values(color).all(count);
      setList(colors);
    } catch (error) {
      setError(true);
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

I also have a similar input which updates my other state variable `color` .What is happening is on submitting the form, `new Values()` is giving me an object with updated value of `color` but old value of `count`

Link to original project: https://github.com/john-smilga/react-projects/blob/master/09-color-generator/final/src/App.js
Link: https://react-projects-9-color-generator.netlify.app/

What I have tried to do:

```
import SingleColor from "./SingleColor";

import Values from "values.js";

function App() {
  const [color, setColor] = useState("");
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(10);               ////////Here
  const [list, setList] = useState(new Values("#f15025").all(10));
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      console.log("Before: " + count);
      let colors = new Values(color).all(count);       /////////Here 
      console.log("After: " + count);
      setList(colors);
    } catch (error) {
      setError(true);
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  return (
    <>
      <section className="container">
        <h3>color generator</h3>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={color}
            placeholder="#f15025"
            onChange={(e) => setColor(e.target.value)}
            className={`${error ? "error" : null} `}
          />
          <input
            type="number"
            value={count}
            onChange={(e) => {
              setCount(e.target.value);            /////////Updating
            }}
            style={{ marginLeft: "5px" }}
          />
          <button className="btn" type="submit">
            submit
          </button>
        </form>
      </section>
      <section className="colors">
        {list.map((color, index) => {
          // console.log(color);
          return (
            <SingleColor
              key={index}
              {...color}
              index={index}
              hexColor={color.hex}
            />
          );
        })}
      </section>
    </>
  );
}
```

**Any other way of dynamically passing the value to the `all` function ?**

Comment: Can you console.log inside the onchange of the count input, `onChange={(e) => {
              setCount((old)=>{console.log(old);return e.target.value});            
            }}` .

Comment: @Kaneki21 Thanks I found the error . The state was getting updated but the value that got passed into the  [all](https://github.com/noeldelgado/values.js/blob/master/src/index.js) function was string and not a number.